# Perl library: Identifier too long

Tags: perl

I am attempting to obfusicate some code, and using a short "pm" library. The code is in the cgi-bin. But I am getting "Identifier too long" errors ... yet the line it's deciphering is only 1016 chars in plain form.

Here is the library:

```
package dml;

use Filter::Simple;

FILTER {
    $_=~tr/[hjndr 9_45|863!7]/[acefbd2461507938]/;
}
```

And the actual program itself ...

```
BEGIN {
    $path = 'D:/home/cristofa/';
}

use lib $path;
use dml;
! 9_44! 96476_6_68!h9d9d6666669n4!4d454_4 4|4 9n4!4d4 9d4j45634d6|6_9d4 63 ...
no dml;
```

I have shortened the code for obvious reasons.

As well as the "identifier too long", I can change other bits, (I think removing filter::simple and using tr~ on its own) and then get "NO is not allowed" referring to the 'no dml' line. I tried putting the data into $_='! 9_44 ...' but that comes back re changing a read only value!!!

If you're curious, the first two figures above SHOULD convert to "3d". I step through the decoded string two at a time, and thus hex for the above is "=", (since the first line of the decoded file is "$f='xyz';" - and I ran into problems trying to substitute the Dollar back to a variable - I ended up using "=$f='xyz';" in the script and then using $data=~s/=\$/\$/g; when converting)

But my 'dilemma' is why that 1016 byte line is causing the script to throw a "wobbly" when I have another program using a library which decodes 2678 bytes with no problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ perl -E'
    $_ = "! 9_44! 96476_6_68!h9d9d6666669n4!4d454_4 4|4 9n4!4d4 9d4j45634d6|6_9d4 63 ...";
    tr/[hjndr 9_45|863!7]/[acefbd2461507938]/;
    say;
'
3d24663d27687474703a2f2f7777772e636f61646d656d2e636f6d2f6c61796f75742f6d79d...
```

That is indeed a very very long identifier.

That looks like hex. Let's try converting the sequence from hex into bytes and rendering them on a UTF-8 terminal.

```
$ perl -E'
    $_ = "! 9_44! 96476_6_68!h9d9d6666669n4!4d454_4 4|4 9n4!4d4 9d4j45634d6|6_9d4 63 ...";
    tr/[hjndr 9_45|863!7]/[acefbd2461507938]/;
    $_ = pack("H*", $_);
    say;
'
=$f='http://www.coadmem.com/layout/my<garbage>
```

Bingo! You forgot `$_ = pack("H*", $_);` in your filter.

---

By the way, `tr/[abc]/[def]/` is equivalent `tr/][abc/][def/`, which is equivalent to `tr/abc/def/` (except for the returned value you ignore). Get rid of `[` and `]`!

Comment: The "get rid of [ ]" I can understand; just put the letters between the forward slashes. But I'm not so sure about the "$ perl -E' .... say;' part. Since I have the shebang at the top of the script, do I need to put this second line in? Also, to my limited knowledge, isn't the single quotes making the whole SCRIPT into a literal, so how's that working? Re the pack command. Yes there is an unpack in the encoder, so I did miss the latter. Thanks